# Collection validation does not work + laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have an `$array` with approx. 100k+ entries.

[image]

I convert the array into a collection using this code:

```php
$insert_data = collect($array);
// Make a collection to use the chunk method
$chunks = $insert_data->chunk(10000);
```

which will create 10 bunches of 10000 records.

Now I want to validate the fields, so I use this code:

```php
$rules2 = [
    'email.*'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
    'phone.*'    => 'required|min:10|unique:users,phone',
    'password.*' => 'required',
];

$rmsgs = [
    'email.unique' => 'The email has already been taken.',
    'phone.unique' => 'The phone has already been taken.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($array, $rules2, $rmsgs);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $m = [];
    $m['message'] = '';
    $xx = $validator->errors();
    foreach ($xx->all() as $message) {
        $m['message'] .= $message;
        $m['message'] .= ',';
    }
    $m['message'] = rtrim($m['message'], ",");
    array_push($msg, $m);
    continue;
}
DB::table('users')->insert($chunk->toArray());
```

**Now this validation does not work while importing the file but it simply does not throw any error in `$msg` array.**

what am I doing wrong? I left email address empty into CSV for some records but it does not return any error.

Comment: Can I suggest, on a long question like this, you make a short version in the top, so it's quick to see if it's something one can be helpful with or not. And perhaps also fix up the indentation and syntax, so it's faster and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion! I added each and every detail of what I am doing and what error I am facing. for better highlighting, I did keep the problem in bold to keep your attention. Looking for a better solution.

Comment: can you give me a dd($array) output in image ?

Comment: I understand the desire to be understood, but the first half of this question is not needed. You have a collection you're trying to validate, we just need to know what the collection looks like and what the validation rules look like. How you created the collection is not relevant.

Comment: You are using `continue` statement outside of a loop context, it will not do anything. Do you mean to use `return`?

Comment: Agreed @miken32  makes sense! `if ($validator->fails()) {` does not do anything I mean If the array has an empty email address then also it does not go inside and `$msg` gets blank always.

Comment: I'm not shaming anyone. I'm giving you an advice that do not use words that are not understood outside India, causing your issue not to be understood properly here. If it's unclear still to you, rest of the world uses words like "thousand", "million", "billion" etc. Not "lac" / "lakh" or "crore".

Comment: Sorry what? Are you saying that everyone should start using whatever words they want here, not the ones that everyone else understands?

Comment: LOL I am not responsible for what words everyone is using the only concern is just to understand the question and see exactly below the answer is accepted without a single discussion on lac or lakh LOL DONT waste my and your time please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do that

```
$rules2 = [
    '*.email'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
    '*.phone'    => 'required|min:10|unique:users,phone',
    '*.password' => 'required'
];
```

and you must do it in cron job

Comment: This works! but the execution stops by inserting the 1 bunch of records like 5k records inserted and given error but rest 95k remains un-executed.

Comment: you must do it in cron job

Comment: preferring laravel-excel instead

Comment: Chunk did the job.. I have divided the file into 1000 chunks of the array and put it into the queue meaning multiple jobs like 100 jobs and it will keep running in the jobs in the background on finishing I am sending an email to the admin user via appserviceprovider in boot method.